# Is there any reason *to* upgrade the biochip in Deus Ex:HR?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I know the reason *not* to upgrade the biochip, but is there any way upgrading the biochip will help you?

Comment: Are you talking about the Biochip update that supposedly fixes [the glitch](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/The_Glitch)?

Comment: Yes. It's the one that you can fix in the LIMB clinic in Hengsha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. There are no upsides or benefits to upgrading - at all.

The purpose of this "upgrade" is to allow the Illuminati direct control over everybody with cybernetic augmentations by granting the ability to shut down a users' cybernetics remotely.

Visiting the LIMB clinics to get this upgrade will allow your augmentations (including your HUD) to be disabled, most notably during the Jaron Namir encounter.

The creation of this glitch is what is actually being discussed during the opening scene;

> "I have spoken with Montreal. The broadcast satellites are ours when we need them. A few weeks of discomfort, and the public will be primed for our recall."

Additionally, there are several emails that you can find throughout the later stages of the game that discuss the creation of the glitch.

Comment: I know that your augs are disabled during that boss fight, but I was more asking if there's a point where the "glitch" is a problem if you choose not to upgrade.

Comment: @Keavon this is covered in the first word of my answer - "No", there are no upsides or benefits  to upgrading - at all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It prevents [the glitch](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/The_Glitch) from occurring.

Comment: Do you mean periodically at random times throughout the game?

Comment: I mean at scripted times, from after you get the option to upgrade (I don't recall it happening periodically).